# How do I apply a Find and Replace only to the selected text and not the whole document in VB.net

Tags: .net, vb.net, richtextbox, replace

Right, I have already created the code that allows the user to perform a **Find and Replace** on all the text within a Rich Text Box. However, I now what to allow the user to select part of the text on which to perform the **Find and Replace**

This is my code I am currently using:

```
Private Sub btnFFindNext_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles btnFFindNext.Click
Dim length as String

length = textToFind.Text.Length

lastposition = frm1.RichTextBox.Find(textToFind.Text, lastposition, RichTextBoxFinds.None)

frm1.RichTextBox.SelectionStart = lastposition
frm1.RichTextBox.SelectionLength = length
lastposition = lastposition + 1
```

I have also added code within the RTB on form1 selection changed event handler, so that when it changes, it sets the current cursor position as the **lastposition**.

Hopefully the above code and my description will help you understand my situation. So just for clarification, how would I adapt my code so that if the user selects some text, then it only performs the `Find and Replace` on that text. Once it reaches the end of the selection, it ends.

Thank you.

Comment: Any one got any advice at least?

Comment: Please do **not** add answers as follow up replies to your question, edit your question or leave comments instead. I tried to move them into your question, but could not, each one specifically addressed an answer.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend to use `MouseUp` and `MouseDown` events to capture the selections and then find out the search string within a range of selection.

You can also look at [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.richtextbox.find%28v=vs.71%29.aspx) MSDN example, or something like this would help you:

```
Private selectionStart As Integer
Private selectionEnd As Integer
Private searchString As String

Private Sub btnFindAll_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs)
    searchString = textToFind.Text   ' Set string to find here

    ' Swap position due to reverse selection
    If selectionStart > selectionEnd Then
        Dim x As Integer = selectionStart
        selectionStart = selectionEnd
        selectionEnd = x
    End If

    'Every time find index and focus the result
    Dim index As Integer = richTextBox1.Find(searchString, selectionStart, selectionEnd, RichTextBoxFinds.None)
    If index > 0 Then
        richTextBox1.Focus()
        richTextBox1.Select(index, searchString.Length)
        selectionStart = index + searchString.Length
    Else
                ' not found
    End If
End Sub

Private Sub richTextBox1_MouseUp(sender As Object, e As MouseEventArgs)
    selectionEnd = richTextBox1.GetCharIndexFromPosition(New System.Drawing.Point(e.X, e.Y))
End Sub

Private Sub richTextBox1_MouseDown(sender As Object, e As MouseEventArgs)
    selectionStart = richTextBox1.GetCharIndexFromPosition(New System.Drawing.Point(e.X, e.Y))
End Sub
```

Comment: Use your button event handler and from link just use the code within event handler

Comment: For my findnext event handler would it be this?

    Private Sub btnFFindNext_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles btnFFindNext.Click
        Call FindMyText(RichTextBox.SelectedText, RichTextBox.SelectionStart, RichTextBox.Text.Length)
    End Sub

So I'm passing the selectedText as the "searchText". I'm passing the selectionStart as the "searchStart". Now, what do I pass in as the "searchEnd"? Because it's definitely not RTB.Text.Length

Comment: for `searchEnd` you should see my code's `MoueseDown` event. here i have captured the final boundary of the selection. OR you can use `RTB.SelectedText.Length` or `RTB.SelectionLength`

Comment: I'm going to use the "answer my question" button rather than commenting so that you can see my code better.